# Why using Boolean in filter in js return the true values only?

Tags: javascript, filter

I've put an array and use filter and put a Boolean in it like this

The output is the true values only.
My question is why Boolean return the true values only? Isn't a false value considered a boolean ??

```js
let constTrue = [true, false, true].filter(Boolean);

console.log(constTrue);
```

Comment: `Boolean(false) === false` and if the predicate returns `false` the value is excluded by `filter`

Comment: [Array filter docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - the `Boolean` function doesn't check if a value is Boolean, it (basically) creates a Boolean

Comment: I think you're mixing up 2 possible things here `Boolean(value)` vs `new Boolean(value)` they do different things. In the latter case no values will be filtered as the returned Boolean object will always be truthy. I'm not sure how useful that would be though and depends on the use-case you have.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Both take a callback function which they run on every value in the array.

`filter` returns a new array containing all the original values for which the function returns a true value. `Boolean(false)` doesn't return a true value, so those values are omitted.

`map` returns a new array containing the return value of the callback function for each and every one of the original values.